# jquery: autocomplete:: change event not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have implemented jquery autocomplete for a text field. The text fields shows a range of values fetched from the database.

As the user can also type in the text field, I want check whether the user has selected a value from the available list and want to show an alert message if any random value is typed. For this, I tried a code as below but it did not work:

```
$('#txt').autocomplete({
        url: '/ABC.action?autocompleteABC=',
        minChars: 0,
        max: 4000,
        width: 150,
        scroll: true,
        cacheLength: 0,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            alert('inside');
            if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) 
            {
                alert('invalid value entered');
            } 
        }
     });
```

Please advise.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

your code will work if you close the **if** statement with an **else** like this

```
$('#txt').autocomplete({
  url: '/ABC.action?autocompleteABC=',
    source:['apple','banana'],
        minChars: 0,
        max: 4000,
        width: 150,
        scroll: true,
        cacheLength: 0,
        change: function (event, ui) {

            if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) 
            {
                alert('invalid value entered');
            }else{// else statement
             alert('inside');} 
        }
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dkqkdpo/

Comment: Hi Napster3world, I did try the way you suggested but it did not work. Here are the jquery files I am using: jquery-1.2.6.min.js
ui.autocomplete.min.js
ui.core.min.js. Do i need to use any other version to make my code work?

Comment: compile a jsfiddle with external resource and i'll try to fix your code

Comment: Tried a code as following too, but it did not work: $('#txt').autocomplete({
  url: '/ABC/XYZ.action?autocomplete=',
  minChars: 0,
        max: 4000,
        width: 150,
        scroll: true,
        cacheLength: 0,
        }).bind('autocompletechange', function(event, ui) {
        alert('inside');
    });.................................................. Will compile the fiddle and share the details

Comment: I have created a fiddle with external resource: http://jsfiddle.net/anandtiwari03/607phqo2/. Please help.

Comment: The ui.autocomplete.min.js I am using is 1.6rc2 and it seems the change attribute is not supported in this version. Can someone please suggest how can I make the code work with some later version and minimal code changes ?